# Problem when upgrading from rails 2 to rails 3 (and also ruby version)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I am having an issue while upgrading from rails 2.3.10 to rails 3
I am upgrading an existing project, what I did is create a brand new rails 3.0.9 project copy over the code (models, views etc...) and changing the things that the rails_upgrade plugin recommended.

Also, I upgraded the gems etc..

Now, when I try to start the server I have this issue:

```
/Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:123:in `include': wrong argument type Class (expected Module) (TypeError)
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:123:in `add_template_helper'
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:123:in `module_eval'
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:123:in `add_template_helper'
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:98:in `helper'
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:97:in `each'
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:97:in `helper'
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_controller/base.rb:228:in `inherited'
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/bundler/gems/typus-974c0c36221d/app/controllers/admin/base_controller.rb:1
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:227:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:346:in `require_or_load'
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:491:in `load_missing_constant'
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:in `const_missing'
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `each'
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `const_missing'
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/bundler/gems/typus-974c0c36221d/app/controllers/admin/account_controller.rb:1
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:227:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:346:in `require_or_load'
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:300:in `depend_on'
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:216:in `require_dependency'
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:138:in `eager_load!'
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:137:in `each'
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:137:in `eager_load!'
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:135:in `each'
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:135:in `eager_load!'
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:209:in `to_proc'
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:11:in `each'
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:11:in `all'
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:107:in `eager_load!'
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:41
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `run_initializers'
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
from /Users/avitzurel/Dropbox/Projects/gogobot_rails3/config/environment.rb:5
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
from /Users/avitzurel/Dropbox/Projects/gogobot_rails3/config.ru:3
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
from /Users/avitzurel/Dropbox/Projects/gogobot_rails3/config.ru:1:in `new'
from /Users/avitzurel/Dropbox/Projects/gogobot_rails3/config.ru:1
```

This is my gemfile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.9'

gem 'ar-extensions'
gem 'authlogic'
gem 'oauth'
gem 'twitter_oauth'
gem 'koala'
gem 'htmlentities'
# gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'
gem 'right_aws'
gem "typus", :git => "git://github.com/typus/typus.git", :branch => "3-0-stable"
gem 'flickraw'
gem 'delayed_job', '>= 2.0.4'
gem 'friendly_id', '3.1.7'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0'
gem 'rubyzip', :require => 'zip/zip'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'jammit'
gem 'mysql2', '< 0.3'
gem 'dalli'
gem 'closure-compiler'
gem 'yui-compressor', :require => 'yui/compressor'
gem 'geokit'
gem 'text'
gem 'fastercsv'
gem 'rapleaf_api'
gem 'hashie'
gem 'foursquare'
gem 'foursquare2'
gem 'oauth2'
gem 'google_places'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'juggernaut'
gem 'factory_girl'
gem 'whenever'
gem 'twitter'
gem 'sunspot', :require => 'sunspot'
gem 'sunspot_rails', :require => 'sunspot/rails'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', :require => 'bcrypt'
gem 'validatable'
gem 'redis'
gem 'redis-namespace'

# Use unicorn as the web server
gem 'unicorn'
gem 'capistrano'

group :development, :test do

end
```

This is my plugins list:

```
acts_as_abusable  
acts_as_loggable  
annotate_models   
daemon_generator  
masochism         
mysql_bigint      
perform_later     
sitemap_generator
acts_as_likable   
acts_as_solr      
bitmask-attribute 
gogo_cache        
mobile-fu
oauth2_provider   
resque
```

I am struggling with this one for a few hours now and I would love an answer.

Thanks.

EDIT:
This is the stacktrace after I removed typus completely:

```
/Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:123:in `include': wrong argument type Class (expected Module) (TypeError)
    from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:123:in `add_template_helper'
    from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:123:in `module_eval'
    from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:123:in `add_template_helper'
    from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:98:in `helper'
    from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:97:in `each'
    from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:97:in `helper'
    from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_controller/base.rb:228:in `inherited'
    from /Users/avitzurel/Dropbox/Projects/gogobot_rails3/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1
    from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:227:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:346:in `require_or_load'
    from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:491:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:in `const_missing'
    from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `each'
    from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `const_missing'
    from /Users/avitzurel/Dropbox/Projects/gogobot_rails3/app/controllers/abuse_reports_controller.rb:1
    from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:227:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:346:in `require_or_load'
    from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:300:in `depend_on'
    from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:216:in `require_dependency'
    from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:138:in `eager_load!'
    from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:137:in `each'
    from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:137:in `eager_load!'
    from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:135:in `each'
    from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:135:in `eager_load!'
    from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:108:in `eager_load!'
    from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:41
    from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
    from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
    from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
    from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/avitzurel/Dropbox/Projects/gogobot_rails3/config/environment.rb:5
    from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Users/avitzurel/Dropbox/Projects/gogobot_rails3/config.ru:3
    from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/avitzurel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@gogo_web/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
    from /Users/avitzurel/Dropbox/Projects/gogobot_rails3/config.ru:1:in `new'
    from /Users/avitzurel/Dropbox/Projects/gogobot_rails3/config.ru:1
```

Comment: What's on line 1 of app/controllers/admin/base_controller.rb ?

Comment: I removed typus completely from the system, removed all of the controllers, it then said the error is on the first line of another controller, just a standard controller.

Comment: Did you verify you are including Typus correctly? Can you share the stacktrace after removing typus?

Comment: Edited: added the trace after the removal of typus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
`include': wrong argument type Class (expected Module) (TypeError)
```

Maybe one of your helpers has been accidentally redefined as a `Class`

```
# app/helpers/application_helper.rb
# make sure you never say "# class ApplicationHelper"
module ApplicationHelper
```

You could check your whole app with this grep command:

```
egrep -Ri "class.*Helper" *
```

If you find anything, double-check it shouldn't be a `Module` instead.

Comment: I am accepting your answer, since this was the problem, I actually answered myself as well but nicer to accept yours :-)

Comment: Thank you :) I was pasting it in when the bar appeared at the top saying an answer had been added.

Answer (score 3):

So, it's fixed now...

what I did was to edit this file helpers.rb:123:in `include' (where the problem was in rails)
I just output the module name which is currently loading, turns out that one the the files in the app/helpers folder was a class (someone put it there months ago).

Once I removed this file to the lib folder, rails loaded up nicely.

And thanks to @arikfr for the tip to edit this file :-)